Calling a function stops printing anything to stdout when using `echo`
I am running a bash script, and it is strange that after a line of calling function, echo in the called function does not print anything.
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash
foo() {
    echo 1 # not print in stdout
    echo "I want to return this string"
}

main() {
    echo 0 # print in stdout
    count="$(foo)"
}

main "$@"

$ ./test.sh
0

How do I get called functions to echo to stdout?

You capture the entire output of foo (both echo statements) and store it in count. What happens when you do echo $count at the end of main?

It is writing to standard output, and $(...) captures it to assign to count. If you want to write to the terminal, regardless of what happens to standard output, write to /dev/tty.

@JoachimSauer if I echo "$count" at the end of main(), then I got "0\n1\nI want to return this string". So count captures all lines printed in "foo()".

@chepner ok thanks. How can I do that? echo xxx > /dev/tty? And another question arises: how can I let count() only captures the last line of echo in foo()? As sometimes I want to print some debug lines, but I don't know how to, as all lines would be captured and returned, if I don't want to mess up with returned value I cannot print any other lines in between

You could try sending your debug output to stderr instead of stdout: echo someDebugStuff 1>&2. It's not quite clean, IMO but should work.

echo someDebugStuff >&2 would be sufficient.

ok so how about a function like debuglog() { echo "$@" >&2 }? Then call it like if (debug); then debuglog "msg"; fi;

OK both fastest answers are good so upvote both and accept the 2nd one, to balance a little bit.

As others have mentioned, count="$(foo)" is capturing all of the stdout from foo which is why you don't see 0 on your terminal, it's inside of count along with I want to return this string.
Code such as you show almost always is better written with those extra echos going to stderr than stdout as they're usually for things like printing prompts, progress indicators, debugging/tracing information, error messages, etc. which you don't want getting mixed in with the actual final output of your script.
Given that, this is probably what you want:
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
foo() {
    echo 1 >&2 # print in stderr
    echo "I want to return this string"
}

main() {
    echo 0 >&2 # print in stderr
    count="$(foo)"
}

main "$@"

which when run as this would print those values to stderr:
$ ./tst.sh
0
1

and if you really wanted them to go to stdout, which I highly doubt, you could always do:
$ ./tst.sh >&1
0
1

or put that redirection in your code too:
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
foo() {
    echo 1 >&2 # print in stderr
    echo "I want to return this string"
}

main() {
    echo 0 >&2 # print in stderr
    count="$(foo)"
}

main "$@" 2>&1 # redirect stderr to stdout


$ ./tst.sh
0
1

Reading your comment made me wonder if you actually could benefit from a different type of solution than output redirection plus command substitution - a name reference variable. For example:
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

foo() {
    local -n result=$1  # "-n" lets us declare a function-local variable
                        # "result" as being a reference to the variable
                        # passed as the first argument when this function
                        # is called instead of a separate object.

    echo 1              # print in stdout

    result="I want to return this string"
}

main() {
    local count         # Just a regular function-local variable.

    echo 0              # print in stdout

    foo count           # This will set "count" indirectly inside foo().

    printf 'count="%s"\n' "$count"      # print in stdout
}

main "$@"


$ ./tst.sh
0
1
count="I want to return this string"

That allows you to set a variable inside foo() that can be used by main() without it being a global variable, just like you can with passing arguments by reference in many programming languages such as C. As a benefit over count=$(foo), this approach doesn't require spawning a sub-process as required by command substitution so it'll execute faster.

OK so if I don't do 2>&1 what happens? I am confused by main "$@" 2>&1 but I understand other parts. If you do 2>&1 then all to &2 will go to &1 and it does not affect what happens in main()?

Right, redirection of output from a function or script cannot affect what happens within that function or script. Imagine you have a script named foo containing echo 'hello' | sed 's/h/H/'. When you run it as ./foo, internally echo 'hello's output feeds into the pipe and then becomes the input for sed. Externally Hello is printed to stdout and displayed on your terminal. If you run it as ./foo > file then externally foos output will now go to file instead of your terminal but within foo the output of echo 'hello' still goes to the pipe+sed, it doesn't go to file.

To learn more about IO redirection you could take a look at questions on stackexchange tagged with io-redirection and the "about" for that tag and in particular you can take any answers you come across posted by Stéphane Chazelas as gospel.

Thanks, the 1st time in 5 yrs  seeing someone in SOF to recommend others' answers.

You're welcome. After reading one of your comments I realized you may actually want something different from output redirection so I updated my answer to add an alternative.

Command substitution captures the stdout of the enclosed command and is replaced by it. Use a different file descriptor for the output.
#!/bin/bash
foo() {
    echo 1 >&3  # This won't be returned
    echo "I want to return this string"
}


main() {
    echo 0  # Print in stdout
    count="$(foo)"
    echo "C: $count"
}

exec 3>&1

main "$@"

exec 3>&-

Here, the first output line from foo goes to file descriptor 3, and before calling it, redirect it to the standard output.

I would be precise and say that it writes to file descriptor 3, no matter what standard output is when foo is called.

@chepner: Reformulated, thanks. I also moved the redirection closer to the calling line so it's clear it doesn't influence the definition of the function.

nit: command substitution does not "return it as a string".  return has too much meaning to be used like this.  The value returned by command substitution is the same as the value returned by the command.  eg the expression$(echo foo; exit 3) evaluates to the string "foo" and returns 3.

@WilliamPursell: Reformulated using "replaced" as in man bash.

@WilliamPursell right. It's kind of unfortunate that in shell we use exit to set the exit status of a script but return to set the exit status of a function and that in C-like languages code like bar() { printf("this"); return 9; } ... foo=bar() would display this to stdout and set foo to 9 while in shell it'd display nothing on stdout, set foo to this, and set $? to 9. IMHO we should avoid using the word return when talking about the results of functions or scripts and just talk about their output (gets printed) and their exit status (gets set by return/exit).

Thanks. What does exec 3>&1 and exec 3>&- mean? Put &3 back to &1?

@WesternGun: Roughly, yes. Read about redirection in man bash.

Simply call the function directly in the main function without storing it in a variable.
also if you echo the $count variable it will then show the results
main() {
    echo 0
    foo
}

or do something like below, it will allow the echo statements in foo to print to stdout.
main() {
    echo 0
    
    # do either like this
    echo -e "$(foo)"

    # or like this
    foo

    # or like this
    count="$(foo)"
    echo $count
}


The OP seems to want to capture one output of the function but not the other.  None of the alternatives presented here achieve that.

Ye @JohnBollinger you are right I want to put that into a variable. If I could put the value into a global variable, then I don't have to do it like this, but I cannot. The global var is never changed.  And I don't want to eval.
